# There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection. Falling back

Tags: android, error-handling, bluetooth

I am getting following error whenever my device try to connected with device which is out of range or which is can't connect. if connection is establish then app working fine.

First of all let me tell you ,this question is asked many time before in this site. I go through all that solution but none of that working for me.

Error Occurs at when try to connect in my case at sock.connect. you will see that in my bluetooth manager.

code of Bluetooth manager:

```
public class BluetoothManager {

private static final String TAG = BluetoothManager.class.getName();

private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

public static BluetoothSocket connect(BluetoothDevice dev) throws IOException {
    BluetoothSocket sock = null;
    BluetoothSocket sockFallback = null;

    Log.d(TAG, "Starting Bluetooth connection..");
    try {
        sock = dev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        sock.connect();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection. Falling back..", e1);
        Class<?> clazz = sock.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[]{Integer.TYPE};
        try {
            Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
            Object[] params = new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)};
            sockFallback = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(sock.getRemoteDevice(), params);
            sockFallback.connect();
            sock = sockFallback;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't fallback while establishing Bluetooth connection.");

        }
    }
    return sock;
}
}
```

Log:

```
E/com.quad14.obdnewtry.io.BluetoothManager: There was an error while establishing Bluetooth connection. Falling back..
    java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:738)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:750)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:375)
        at com.quad14.obdnewtry.io.BluetoothManager.connect(BluetoothManager.java:24)
        at com.quad14.obdnewtry.io.ObdGatewayService.startObdConnection(ObdGatewayService.java:116)
        at com.quad14.obdnewtry.io.ObdGatewayService.startService(ObdGatewayService.java:89)
        at com.quad14.obdnewtry.activity.MainActivity$16.onServiceConnected(MainActivity.java:1043)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1453)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1481)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```